# Unique Distancing Problem, Memoization in Haskell

Tags: python, performance, haskell, memoization

**note:** You might be scared seeing the length of the post, but it's actually not that long because you don't need to read the compiler logs or the python code to understand my code (I wish StackExchange allowed foldable code like [github](https://github.com/dear-github/dear-github/issues/166#issuecomment-236342209)).

---

I've been reading CodeReview for a while but this is my first post here. This is also my first Haskell program. I've tried to learn Haskell unsuccessfully before, so I was looking for a puzzle to program in haskell, to go head first in the world of pure functionnal programming.

The code bellow is basically a brute-force solution to [Matt Parker's Unique Distancing Problem](https://youtu.be/M_YOCQaI5QI). The challenge is to find a way of arranging N counters on a N by N grid such that every distance is different, [Matt Parker's video](https://youtu.be/M_YOCQaI5QI) explains it well. I stepped up the difficulty a bit by generalising this to any dimensions (2 by 3 by 4 grid for example) and any number of counters.

So having nowhere to start, I made a python script in imperative style and gradually removed assignations and mutable object in favor of list comprehensions and functions. I then rewrote the program in Haskell, and spends countless hours searching things on the web. (I know my python code is very very bad but please focus on the haskell version.)

Python Code

```py
import math

def nd_range(d):
    return ((j,) + i for i in nd_range(d[1:]) for j in range(d[0])) if d else ((),)

def g(candidate, dists, counters, n, dims):
    return () if counters and any((not d or d in dists or dists.add(d)) for d in (math.dist(candidate, counter) for counter in counters))else f(n - 1, dims, counters | {candidate})

def f(n, dims, counters=set()):
    dists = {math.dist(i, j) for i in counters for j in counters}
    return {x for candidate in nd_range(dims) for x in g(candidate, dists.copy(), counters, n, dims)} if n else {frozenset(counters)} if counters else set()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print(len(f(6, (6, 6))))
```

So, I have no idea on how to optimise Haskell code, I did A-B testing every time i made a modification to see if it was faster or slower. For 6 counters and a 6 by 6 grid, the Haskell code now takes 33s on my computer while Python takes 170s (unfair comparison since i've not writen good python).

Haskell Code

```hs
import qualified Data.Set as Set

type P = [Int] -- Point
type S = Set.Set P -- Solution (Set of Point) :: Set [Int]
type SS = Set.Set S -- Set of possible Solutions (Set of Set of Points) :: Set Set [Int]

-- List the points of an N-Dimentionnal grid with dimentions given as [width, height, depth,...]
-- Example: nd_range [1,2,3] gives us [[0,0,0],[0,0,1],[0,0,2],[0,1,0],[0,1,1],[0,1,2]]
nd_range :: [Int] -> [P]
nd_range [] = [[]]
nd_range d = [(j : i) | j <- [0..(pred(head d))], i <- nd_range (tail d)]

-- returns the square of the distance between two N-Dimentionnal points
dist :: P -> P -> Int
dist a = sum . zipWith (((^2).).(-)) a
-- This function comes from https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/70539 and is noticeably faster than mine:
-- dist a b = sum (map (^2) (zipWith (-) a b))

countDists candidate i (dists, n)
    | Set.member d dists = (dists, n)
    | otherwise = (Set.insert d dists, n+1)
    where d = dist candidate i

-- returns the set of all distances between points of a set
dists :: S -> Set.Set Int
dists counter = Set.fromList [ dist i j | i <- Set.toList counter, j <- Set.toList counter]

-- returns True if the point given satisfies the unique distancing constrain given the other points
isPossible :: P -> S -> Bool
isPossible candidate counter = snd (foldr (countDists candidate) (dists counter, 0) counter) == length counter

-- recursively runs for every possible points (back-tracking style) and flattens result into a set
f :: Int -> [Int] -> S -> SS
f 0 dims counter = Set.singleton counter
f n dims counter = Set.fromList [ x |
    candidate <- nd_range dims,
    x <- Set.toList (if isPossible candidate counter
                        then f (n-1) dims (Set.insert candidate counter)
                        else Set.empty)]

-- calls the main recursive function with initial empty set of point
solve :: Int -> [Int] -> SS
solve n dims = f n dims Set.empty

ans = solve 6 [6, 6]
main = print ans >> print ( length ans )
```

The majority of the ressources are utilised to compute distances, as you can see using the profiler, I think it says that the dist function was called 352542672 times (maybe it's not what it means), but since there are only 648 possible pairs of points, I was wondering on how to improve on the performances.

Profiler log

```
    total time  =      134.88 secs   (134876 ticks @ 1000 us, 1 processor)
    total alloc = 216,038,138,480 bytes  (excludes profiling overheads)

COST CENTRE  MODULE    SRC                            %time %alloc

dist         Main      parker_dist.hs:15:1-38          66.2   73.9
countDists   Main      parker_dist.hs:(19,1)-(22,30)   16.3   12.3
isPossible   Main      parker_dist.hs:30:1-110          8.2    3.8
dists        Main      parker_dist.hs:26:1-91           3.9    5.5
countDists.d Main      parker_dist.hs:22:11-30          2.2    0.0
nd_range     Main      parker_dist.hs:(10,1)-(11,73)    2.0    4.2
f            Main      parker_dist.hs:(34,1)-(39,40)    1.2    0.3


                                                                                           individual      inherited
COST CENTRE         MODULE                SRC                           no.     entries  %time %alloc   %time %alloc

MAIN                MAIN                  <built-in>                    138           0    0.0    0.0   100.0  100.0
 CAF                Main                  <entire-module>               275           0    0.0    0.0   100.0  100.0
  ans               Main                  parker_dist.hs:45:1-20        278           1    0.0    0.0   100.0  100.0
   solve            Main                  parker_dist.hs:43:1-33        279           1    0.0    0.0   100.0  100.0
    f               Main                  parker_dist.hs:(34,1)-(39,40) 280     2090329    1.2    0.3   100.0  100.0
     isPossible     Main                  parker_dist.hs:30:1-110       282    74837124    8.2    3.8    96.8   95.5
      countDists    Main                  parker_dist.hs:(19,1)-(22,30) 283   352542672   16.3   12.3    76.5   77.6
       countDists.d Main                  parker_dist.hs:22:11-30       284   352542672    2.2    0.0    60.3   65.3
        dist        Main                  parker_dist.hs:15:1-38        285   352542672   58.1   65.3    58.1   65.3
      dists         Main                  parker_dist.hs:26:1-91        286     2078808    3.9    5.5    12.1   14.1
       dist         Main                  parker_dist.hs:15:1-38        287    46638684    8.1    8.6     8.1    8.6
     nd_range       Main                  parker_dist.hs:(10,1)-(11,73) 281     6236427    2.0    4.2     2.0    4.2
  main              Main                  parker_dist.hs:46:1-40        276           1    0.0    0.0     0.0    0.0
 CAF                Data.Set.Internal     <entire-module>               274           0    0.0    0.0     0.0    0.0
 CAF                GHC.Conc.Signal       <entire-module>               238           0    0.0    0.0     0.0    0.0
 CAF                GHC.IO.Encoding       <entire-module>               219           0    0.0    0.0     0.0    0.0
 CAF                GHC.IO.Encoding.Iconv <entire-module>               217           0    0.0    0.0     0.0    0.0
 CAF                GHC.IO.Handle.FD      <entire-module>               208           0    0.0    0.0     0.0    0.0
 CAF                GHC.IO.Handle.Text    <entire-module>               206           0    0.0    0.0     0.0    0.0
 main               Main                  parker_dist.hs:46:1-40        277           0    0.0    0.0     0.0    0.0
```

My guess is that memoization is not possible as easily as in python because it uses mutable state to work (in python, you just add `@lru_cache(maxsize=n)` in front of your function). So if you have any suggestions on how to implement memoization or on how to improve my code, feel free to share them.

---

## Update 1

Achieved 25% better performance by using memoization. Problem: I need to know the number of dimensions of the key to build the HashMap (Here I just assume it's [6, 6]).

```hs
dist' a = sum . zipWith (((^2).).(-)) a
distHash = HashMap.fromList [((i, j), dist' i j) | i <- nd_range [6, 6], j <- nd_range [6, 6]]
dist i j = case HashMap.lookup (i, j) distHash of
    Just d -> d
    Nothing -> dist' i j
```

## Update 2

I realized that I could define `dims` and the number of counters as global constants, now I don't have to pass it around to functions.

```hs
dims = [6, 6]
nCounters = 6
```

## Update 3

I'm going to revert this whole memoization thing because it improves by 25% the speed when running with the profiler but it is twice slower when running without the profiler. (51s without profiler with memoization, 28s without profiler without memoization) Here is the logs, as we can see, it worked, `dist'` is now called `1296` times. But maybe I should ask myself why the function `dist` was called 350 million times in the first place. Also, `hashingWithSalt1` is slow, I wonder if there is a faster hashmap for memoization.

```
    total time  =      105.05 secs   (105051 ticks @ 1000 us, 1 processor)
    total alloc = 66,890,764,984 bytes  (excludes profiling overheads)

COST CENTRE   MODULE              SRC                              %time %alloc

dist          Main                parker_dist.hs:(26,1)-(28,24)     38.2   14.3
hashWithSalt1 Data.Hashable.Class Data/Hashable/Class.hs:271:1-45   22.7   19.1
countDists    Main                parker_dist.hs:(30,1)-(33,30)     17.5   39.7
isPossible    Main                parker_dist.hs:41:1-110            8.3   12.2
hash          Data.HashMap.Base   Data/HashMap/Base.hs:166:1-28      4.6    0.0
dists         Main                parker_dist.hs:37:1-91             3.8   13.7
f             Main                parker_dist.hs:(45,1)-(50,40)      1.9    1.0
sparseIndex   Data.HashMap.Base   Data/HashMap/Base.hs:1867:1-42     1.4    0.0
countDists.d  Main                parker_dist.hs:33:11-30            1.1    0.0


                                                                                                                  individual      inherited
COST CENTRE                    MODULE                   SRC                                    no.     entries  %time %alloc   %time %alloc

MAIN                           MAIN                     <built-in>                             153           0    0.0    0.0   100.0  100.0
 CAF                           Main                     <entire-module>                        305           0    0.0    0.0   100.0  100.0
  ans                          Main                     parker_dist.hs:56:1-21                 308           1    0.0    0.0   100.0  100.0
   solve                       Main                     parker_dist.hs:54:1-23                 309           1    0.0    0.0   100.0  100.0
    f                          Main                     parker_dist.hs:(45,1)-(50,40)          311     2090329    1.9    1.0   100.0  100.0
     isPossible                Main                     parker_dist.hs:41:1-110                315    74837124    8.3   12.2    98.1   99.0
      countDists               Main                     parker_dist.hs:(30,1)-(33,30)          316   352542672   17.5   39.7    78.0   69.2
       countDists.d            Main                     parker_dist.hs:33:11-30                317   352542672    1.1    0.0    60.5   29.5
        dist                   Main                     parker_dist.hs:(26,1)-(28,24)          318   352542672   33.5   12.6    59.4   29.5
         sparseIndex           Data.HashMap.Base        Data/HashMap/Base.hs:1867:1-42         335   435640214    1.2    0.0     1.2    0.0
         hash                  Data.HashMap.Base        Data/HashMap/Base.hs:166:1-28          319   352542672    4.1    0.0    24.6   16.9
          hashWithSalt1        Data.Hashable.Class      Data/Hashable/Class.hs:271:1-45        320   705085344   20.1   16.9    20.5   16.9
           defaultHashWithSalt Data.Hashable.Class      Data/Hashable/Class.hs:290:1-50        321  2115256032    0.5    0.0     0.5    0.0
      dists                    Main                     parker_dist.hs:37:1-91                 336     2078808    3.8   13.7    11.8   17.6
       dist                    Main                     parker_dist.hs:(26,1)-(28,24)          337    46638684    4.6    1.7     8.0    3.9
        sparseIndex            Data.HashMap.Base        Data/HashMap/Base.hs:1867:1-42         341    56733713    0.2    0.0     0.2    0.0
        hash                   Data.HashMap.Base        Data/HashMap/Base.hs:166:1-28          338    46638684    0.5    0.0     3.2    2.2
         hashWithSalt1         Data.Hashable.Class      Data/Hashable/Class.hs:271:1-45        339    93277368    2.6    2.2     2.7    2.2
          defaultHashWithSalt  Data.Hashable.Class      Data/Hashable/Class.hs:290:1-50        340   279832104    0.1    0.0     0.1    0.0
  dims                         Main                     parker_dist.hs:9:1-13                  314           1    0.0    0.0     0.0    0.0
  distHash                     Main                     parker_dist.hs:24:1-90                 322           1    0.0    0.0     0.0    0.0
   dist'                      'Main                     parker_dist.hs:20:1-39                 326        1296    0.0    0.0     0.0    0.0
   nd_range                    Main                     parker_dist.hs:(15,1)-(16,73)          324           6    0.0    0.0     0.0    0.0
   fromList                    Data.HashMap.Strict.Base Data/HashMap/Strict/Base.hs:598:1-64   323           1    0.0    0.0     0.0    0.0
    unsafeInsert               Data.HashMap.Base        Data/HashMap/Base.hs:(784,1)-(814,76)  327        1296    0.0    0.0     0.0    0.0
     copy                      Data.HashMap.Array       Data/HashMap/Array.hs:(328,1)-(333,30) 333        1800    0.0    0.0     0.0    0.0
     sparseIndex               Data.HashMap.Base        Data/HashMap/Base.hs:1867:1-42         334        1474    0.0    0.0     0.0    0.0
     hash                      Data.HashMap.Base        Data/HashMap/Base.hs:166:1-28          328        1296    0.0    0.0     0.0    0.0
      hashWithSalt1            Data.Hashable.Class      Data/Hashable/Class.hs:271:1-45        329        2592    0.0    0.0     0.0    0.0
       defaultHashWithSalt     Data.Hashable.Class      Data/Hashable/Class.hs:290:1-50        330        7776    0.0    0.0     0.0    0.0
     new_                      Data.HashMap.Array       Data/HashMap/Array.hs:256:1-28         332         900    0.0    0.0     0.0    0.0
  main                         Main                     parker_dist.hs:57:1-27                 306           1    0.0    0.0     0.0    0.0
  nCounters                    Main                     parker_dist.hs:10:1-13                 310           1    0.0    0.0     0.0    0.0
  f                            Main                     parker_dist.hs:(45,1)-(50,40)          312           0    0.0    0.0     0.0    0.0
   nd_range                    Main                     parker_dist.hs:(15,1)-(16,73)          313           3    0.0    0.0     0.0    0.0
 CAF                           Data.HashMap.Base        <entire-module>                        303           0    0.0    0.0     0.0    0.0
  bitsPerSubkey                Data.HashMap.Base        Data/HashMap/Base.hs:1858:1-17         331           1    0.0    0.0     0.0    0.0
  empty                        Data.HashMap.Base        Data/HashMap/Base.hs:464:1-13          325           1    0.0    0.0     0.0    0.0
 CAF                           GHC.Conc.Signal          <entire-module>                        254           0    0.0    0.0     0.0    0.0
 CAF                           GHC.IO.Encoding          <entire-module>                        235           0    0.0    0.0     0.0    0.0
 CAF                           GHC.IO.Encoding.Iconv    <entire-module>                        233           0    0.0    0.0     0.0    0.0
 CAF                           GHC.IO.Handle.FD         <entire-module>                        224           0    0.0    0.0     0.0    0.0
 CAF                           GHC.IO.Handle.Text       <entire-module>                        222           0    0.0    0.0     0.0    0.0
 main                          Main                     parker_dist.hs:57:1-27                 307           0    0.0    0.0     0.0    0.0
```

## Update 4

It looks like the compiler is smarter than me for memoization, so I changed strategy, I try to call dist less by memorizing the distances and only looking at the possible points (instead of all the points). Now my code runs under 10secs.

```hs
import qualified Data.Set as Set

type P = [Int] -- Point
type S = Set.Set P -- Solution (Set of Point) :: Set [Int]
type SS = Set.Set S -- Set of possible Solutions (Set of Set of Points) :: Set Set [Int]
type Dists = Set.Set Int

dims = [6, 6]
nCounters = 6

-- List the points of an N-Dimentionnal grid with dimentions given as [width, height, depth,...]
-- Example: ndRange [1,2,3] gives us [[0,0,0],[0,0,1],[0,0,2],[0,1,0],[0,1,1],[0,1,2]]
ndRange :: [Int] -> [P]
ndRange [] = [[]]
ndRange d = [j : i | j <- [0..(pred(head d))], i <- ndRange (tail d)]

-- returns the square of the distance between two N-Dimentionnal points
dist :: P -> P -> Int
dist a = sum . zipWith (((^2).).(-)) a

check :: P -> [P] -> (Dists, Bool) -> (Dists, Bool)
check candidate counters (dists, bool)
    | null counters = (dists, True)
    | Set.member d dists = (dists, False)
    | otherwise = check candidate (tail counters) (Set.insert d dists, True)
    where d = dist candidate (head counters)

f :: Int -> S -> Dists -> S -> SS
f 0 counters dists grid = Set.singleton counters
f n counters dists grid = Set.fromList [x | 
        (newDists, _, candidate) <- Set.toList goods,
        x <- Set.toList (f (n-1) (Set.insert candidate counters) newDists newGrid)
    ] where  
        res = Set.map (\candidate -> 
            let (newDists, isValid) = check candidate (Set.toList counters) (dists, True) 
            in (newDists, isValid, candidate)) grid
        goods = Set.filter (\(_,x,_) -> x) res
        newGrid = Set.map (\(_,_,x) -> x) goods

-- calls the main recursive function with initial empty set of point
solve :: Int -> SS
solve n = f n Set.empty (Set.singleton 0) (Set.fromList (ndRange dims))

ans = solve nCounters
main = print ans
```

---

Congratulations, you've read until the end, what did we learn?

1. Memoization works, but it slows the program
2. Let the compiler do its thing
3. Focus on the complexity of your function
4. Try to pass the partial results down the tree instead of computing something multiple times
5. Folding is great but you can't interrupt it, folding is trivial to re-implement using recursion and it allows you to stop whenever you want, which can *reduce* complexity (no pun intended).